# generate Java classes from DTD with equals() and hashCode() methods

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, cxf-xjc-plugin

I'm get used using XJC tool from command line. But I realized that I'm not able to generate Java classes with `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods using it. I used this:

```
xjc -dtd -d directory -p com.example.package file.dtd
```

I don't know how to generate the methods. My version is:

```
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6" 
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)
```

**1. Is it possible to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods from a DTD file with XJC tool?**

Moreover, I know I can use Maven plugins to achieve this kind of goals. I'm very happy with [The CXF XJC Maven Plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html). I would be very happy if I can do the same job with this Maven plugin.

**1. Is it possible to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods from a DTD file with The CXF XJC Maven Plugin?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating hashCode() and equals() when creating Java classes using Mojo Jaxb2 maven plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062539/generating-hashcode-and-equals-when-creating-java-classes-using-mojo-jaxb2-m)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I'm aware of this question, but I was asking about command line XJC tool in the first question and The CXF XJC Maven Plugin in the second one, not answered there.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB2 Basics includes plug-ins for `hashCode()` and `equals()`

- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/HashCode+plugin
- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Equals+plugin

Comment: I'm asking about the CXF plugin, not this one. and both links give a me "HTTP Status 404"

Comment: both links work now, but again, the information is about a different plugin.