# How do I add an xjc plugin programmatically at runtime?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm generating JAXB classes from an xsd at runtime using XJC. But by default the `maxLength` restriction in the xsd isn't annotated.

I found a plugin to deal with this, [krasa-jaxb-tools](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools). I've added the dependencies to my POM, but I can't seem to add the plugin to the XJC process.

I'm using version 2.2.11 of the jaxb-xjc tools. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-jxc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
    <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to instantiate the plugin, configuring it and passing it to the `generateCode(Plugins[] extensions, ErrorListener errorListener)` method on my `S2JJAXBModel` model, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's my code:

```
SchemaCompiler schemaCompiler = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
schemaCompiler.forcePackageName(packageRoot);

// JAXB Plugin used to get the proper @Size annotations on all fields.
JaxbValidationsPlugins jaxbValidationPlugin = new JaxbValidationsPlugins();

// Build up list of options for the plugin.
// First option must be the name of the plugin itself.
// Options must be prefixed with dashes
String[] args = new String[] { "-" + JaxbValidationsPlugins.PLUGIN_OPTION_NAME };

try {
    // Activate plugin
    jaxbValidationPlugin.parseArgument(new Options(), args, 0);
} catch (BadCommandLineException | IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());

schemaCompiler.parseSchema(inputSource);
S2JJAXBModel model = schemaCompiler.bind();

// Passing the plugin to the method
JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(new Plugin[] {jaxbValidationPlugin}, null);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how the actual implementation of the `#generateCode()` method looks in version 2.2.11

```
// com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.JAXBModelImpl.java

public JCodeModel generateCode(Plugin[] extensions,ErrorListener errorListener) {
    // we no longer do any code generation
    return outline.getCodeModel();
}
```

As you can see, the params are just swallowed.

To add the plugin, you want to access the `Options` found in the `SchemaCompiler` and add your plugin there. Note also that the `parseArgument()` call should be made on the options, not the plugin.

Here's how you accomplish that:

```
SchemaCompiler schemaCompiler = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
schemaCompiler.forcePackageName(packageRoot);

// JAXB Plugin used to get the proper @Size annotations on all fields.
JaxbValidationsPlugins jaxbValidationPlugin = new JaxbValidationsPlugins();

// Build up list of options for the plugin.
// First option must be the name of the plugin itself.
// Options must be prefixed with dashes
String[] args = new String[] { "-" + JaxbValidationsPlugins.PLUGIN_OPTION_NAME };

// Get the options for the schema compiler, this is where we add plugins.
Options schemaCompilerOptions = ((SchemaCompilerImpl) schemaCompiler).getOptions();
schemaCompilerOptions.getAllPlugins().add(jaxbValidationPlugin);

// Call the parseArgument method on the options, not the plugin
// Passing in zero because we want to parse the first argument in the array
try {
    schemaCompilerOptions.parseArgument(args, 0);
} catch (BadCommandLineException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());
schemaCompiler.parseSchema(inputSource);
S2JJAXBModel model = schemaCompiler.bind();

JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(null, null);
```