# Custom annotation with jaxb2-annotate-plugin and XJC tool

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I'm trying to convert bunch of XSD files to Java source POJOs at runtime. These XML schemas will be generated based on some protocol specific model definitions.

I have used the JAXB's XJC to compile the schema to pojo. Started facing problem when I used [Jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) for doing custom annotation.

For testing, I have added following in my schema,

```
<xs:schema xmlns:aa="http://acme.example.com/system" 
           xmlns:another="http://acme.example.com/another" 
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
           xmlns:ncn="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:notification:1.0" 
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox" 
           xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"  
           targetNamespace="http://acme.example.com/system" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

XJC started giving the following error from there after,

> Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you
>   meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?

As per suggestions provided in various sources, added required JARS in XJC's classpath as follows, but nothing seems to workout for me.

> xjc -p com.test 
>   -classpath="jaxb2-basics-annotate-1.0.2.jar;tools-0.4.1.5.jar;comm‌​on‌​s-logging-1.1.1.jar;jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.5;annox-1.0.1.ja‌​r;javaparser-1.0.11.jar;jaxb2-basics-tools-0.9.5.jar" -extension
>   myschema.xsd

I couldn't find a proper example for generating java sources using XJC with jaxb2-annotate-plugin. I cannot add this in my maven/ant, as I mentioned I've to generate xsd and pojo at runtime.

If using the XJC tool as java process is the only way, please let me know,

- What are the dependent jars to be included in classpath?
- How to activate the plugin and -Xannotate switch?

If the pojo generation can be done in other ways with this plugin, please suggest the same.

I'm a newbie in jaxb. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

First, iff with `xjc` you mean the binary `xjc` distributed with JDK (like `xjc.exe` under Windows), XJC plugins (including [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)) don't work with `xjc` binary from JDK.

The reason is that when packaging XJC for JDK, the XJC packages get renamed from 
`com.sun.tools.xjc` to `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc`. Third-party XJC plugins extend `com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin`, not `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Plugin`, this is why they don't work with JDK-packaged XJC.

Next, you say you generate code in the runtime. I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work, you'll need to compile the classes afterwards etc. But OK, I'll assume you know what you do. Anyway, you should not execute XJC via command line in this case. You have a programmatic API via `com.sun.tools.xjc.api.XJC`. Check this question and answers:

- [Add toString, hashCode, equals while generating JAXB classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334372/add-tostring-hashcode-equals-while-generating-jaxb-classes-in-java)
- [How do I add an xjc plugin programmatically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355627/how-do-i-add-an-xjc-plugin-programmatically-at-runtime/33355628)

Related:

- [How to use jaxb2-annotate-plugin with XJC in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525642/how-to-use-jaxb2-annotate-plugin-with-xjc-in-command-line/33551139)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @lexicore. I do compile the classes after plugging some codes in the generated java sources.

Comment: Yes, as you have pointed annotate plugin is not working with xjc binary. Using SchemaCompiler APIs, I have added the plugin to the compiler options, and now it's working fine. However I'm facing issues when  providing episode files for class generation. External binding annotations (.xjb) are working fine, but with internal annotations, episode files are not working throwing 'compiler was unable to honor this annotate customization'. Not sure why such inconsistency is faced with JAXB.

Comment: @Swaminathan.M Episode files use SCD-based customizations (instead of XPath-based). With SCD-based customizations you can't provide proprietary customization elements for some reason. An XJC/JAXB problem.