# Object differ hasChanges where no changes should be detected

Tags: java

I'm using [java-object-diff](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff) to get differences between two objects parsed from xml by JAXB. In below example, I'm using the same string to test if I get no differences, however `log.info("has changes: " + diff5.hasChanges());` logs `true`.

```
JAXBContext context1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
Unmarshaller m1 = context1.createUnmarshaller();
Item base = (Item) m1.unmarshal(new StringReader(s));
Item working = (Item) m1.unmarshal(new StringReader(s));
DiffNode diff5 = ObjectDifferBuilder
        .buildDefault()
        .compare(working, base);
log.info("has changes: " + diff5.hasChanges());
diff5.visit((node, visit) -> {
    final Object baseValue = node.canonicalGet(base);
    final Object workingValue = node.canonicalGet(working);
    final String message = node.getPath() + " changed from " +
            baseValue + " to " + workingValue;
    System.out.println(message);
});
```

The message I get from System.out.println is always the same, saying it has changed from `null` to `<the actual value>` This happens for **every** property. E.g.

```
content changed from null to Mit dem Wasserinonisator
```

I have verified that the both `Items` have the same content and none of the both actualy is not `null`, but the exact same content.

`Item` is a pojo with many subclasses (all getters and setters are present), e.g.

```
public class Item {

@XmlElement(name = "ASIN", required = true)
protected String asin;
@XmlElement(name = "ParentASIN")
protected String parentASIN;
@XmlElement(name = "Errors")
protected Errors errors;
@XmlElement(name = "DetailPageURL")
protected String detailPageURL;
@XmlElement(name = "ItemLinks")
protected ItemLinks itemLinks;
@XmlElement(name = "SalesRank")
protected String salesRank;
@XmlElement(name = "SmallImage")
protected Image smallImage;
}
```

Is there any way to make java-object-diff work, to make it compare the values correctly?

Comment: Obviously  `node.canonicalGet(base)` returns `null`. So what is the implementation of `DiffNode` and  `ObjectDifferBuilder`?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem with your code, but I see a different behavior. When I run the program the `diff5.hasChanges() is false`. Please double-check that you show us the source-code as you run it.

Comment: Ja, das ist auf jeden Fall genau der Code den ich benutze. Bringt es dir was wenn ich die kompletten Klassen poste und xml dazu? @TobiasOtto

Comment: Ich würde mir den gesamten Code ansehen und das Verhalten nachstellen können.

Comment: @Michael Could you post a link to your code so I can take a closer look?

Comment: @SQiShER thanks. Yes sure, here's a project demonstrating the issue https://github.com/baao/objectdiffdemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a closer look at [your code](https://github.com/baao/objectdiffdemo) I know what's wrong. The first problem is the fact, that JAXB doesn't generate `equals` methods. For the most part, that's not a problem, because the `ObjectDiffer` can establish the relationship between objects based on the hierarchy. Things get more complicated when ordered or unordered `Collections` are involved, because the ObjectDiffer needs some kind of way to establish the relationship between the collection items in the base and working instance. By default it relies on the lookup mechanism of the underlying collection (which typically involves on or more of the methods `hashCode`, `equals` or `compareTo`.)

In your case this relationship cannot be established, because none of your classes (but especially those contained in `Lists` and `Sets`) implement a proper `equals` method. This means that instances are only ever equal to themselves. This is further complicated by the fact, that the responsible classes represent value objects and don't have any hard identifier, that could be used to easily establish the relationship. Therefore the only option is to provide custom equals methods that simply compare all properties. The consequence is, that the slightest change on those objects will cause the `ObjectDiffer` to mark the base version as `REMOVED` and the working version as `ADDED`. But it will also not mark them as `CHANGED`, when they haven't actually changed. So that's something.

I'm not sure how easy it is to make JAXB generate custom equals methods, so here are some alternative solutions possible with java-object-diff:

1. Implement your own `de.danielbechler.diff.identity.IdentityStrategy` for the problematic types and provide them to the `ObjectDifferBuilder`, like so (example uses Java 8 Lambdas):

   ```
   ObjectDifferBuilder
     .startBuilding()
     .identity()
     .ofCollectionItems(ItemLinks.class, "itemLink").via((working, base) -> {
       ItemLink workingItemLink = (ItemLink) working;
       ItemLink baseItemLink = (ItemLink) base;
       return StringUtils.equals(workingItemLink.getDescription(), baseItemLink.getDescription())
           && StringUtils.equals(workingItemLink.getURL(), baseItemLink.getURL());
     })
     // ...
     .and().build();
   ```
2. Ignore problematic properties during comparison. Obviously this may not be what you want, but it's an easy solution in case you don't really care about the specific object.

   ```
   ObjectDifferBuilder
     .startBuilding()
     .inclusion()
     .exclude().type(Item.ImageSets.class)
     .and().build();
   ```

A solution that causes JAXB to generate custom equals methods would be my preferred way to go. I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336886/1137104) that claims it's possible, so maybe you want to give this a try first, so you don't have to customize your `ObjectDiffer`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So I will just let JAXB create proper equals methods (or my IDE if first fails) and it'll work. Nice project btw. !