# JAXB 2.1 implement Comparable<T> for the generated Class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin, jaxb2-simplify-plugin

- Using Jaxb 2.1 to generate java code from .xsd
- Jaxb2-basics plug-in is used
- Wants to have generated Class Student to implement Comparable.

  `public class Student implements Serializable, Comparable<Students> {
  ... //bean class...
  public int compareTo(Student other) {
  .....
  return somevalue;
  }
  }`

---

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"
xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance" 
jxb:version="2.1">
<jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xs:date"
            parseMethod="Javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="Javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime" />
        <xjc:serializable uid="12343" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="Student.xsd"
    version="1.0" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Student']/xs:complexType">
        <inheritance:implements>java.lang.Comparable&lt;Student&gt;</inheritance:imple‌​ments>
        <ci:code>public int compareTo(Student other) {

return somevalue;}</ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

---

Plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>xjc</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>-extensions</arguments>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaincludes>
            <include>
            Student.xsd
            </include>
            </schemaincludes>
            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingincludes>
            <include>
            Student.xjb
            </include>
            </bindingincludes>
            <packageName>com.test.model.example</packageName>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/java </outputDirectory>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

---

Error:
Could not process schema files in directory

`Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.3:generate:default:generate-sources)org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:55) at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)`

I am missing something. Any help to resolve is appreciated.

Comment: How do you build it (show the `pom.xml`) and what is the complete error message?

Comment: @lexicore i have updated the plugin which i am using in my POM.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you configure JAXB2 Basics in your `pom.xml`.

Here's a [guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins) for [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin). TL;DR:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>...</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

You're using [jaxb2-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-maven-plugin), I could not find a guide for using XJC plugins in their documentation, but there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136644/303810)

Comment: for inhertance instead of using the mentioned arguments can i use  <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>, do i need to make any changes in .xjb file.

Comment: do i need to make any changes in .xjb file, when i added the plugin , i got a error saying unable to parse the input

Comment: @jcoder Consider to actually start posting your error messages.

Comment: @jcoder This is hardly the complete log. Normally there's a message describing the actual problem. Post your complete `mvn clean install -X -e` lg (via Pastebin, for instance).

Comment: I just keep running into the following error: [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance";. Perhaps you meant "http/jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"? line 7 of type.xsd

Comment: @jcoder This means the inheritance plugin is not activated.

Comment: i have mentioned the same in the pom from the above example. Do i need to add anything

Comment: @jcoder I can help you with [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] (I'm the author). For support with [tag:jaxb2-maven-plugin] you'll need to contact its authors.

Comment: @jcoder Please share a minimal reproducing project via GitHub. I'll take a look.

Comment: the plugin works, i have made some changes in the XSD.